# How can I concatenate two strings using template literals in typeScript?

Tags: typescript

How can I replace **+** with template literals in this case please?

```
.....
filters:[
{ divName: 'CSS'
  levels: [{key: 'GCSS', val:this.name + '(GCSS)'}]
}
],
...
```

Comment: Have you read this page? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: @jtbandes yes, and my problem is with val:this.name it is a declaration so it does not work for me

Comment: Have you tried val:"${this.name} (GCSS)" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
`${this.name}(GCSS)`
```

The **backticks** are important.

Greetings, Flo